# Maths Operations in Analog Clock using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, clock

Why we add (min*360/60)/12 in hourPosition line and (sec * 360/60)/60 in minPosition line ?

```
let hourPosition = hour*360/12 + ((min * 360/60)/12) ;
let minPosition = (min * 360/60) + (sec* 360/60)/60;
let secPosition = sec * 360/60;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: Because it takes 60 * 12 minutes for the hour hand to go around the clock face once, and it takes only 60 minutes for the minute hand to go around once.